# Rails way to write date operations in Mysql

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

Continuing in my Mysql to Rails questions, what is the Rails way of writing the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(searchTerm) AS percent, searches.*  
FROM `searches`
WHERE `results` = 0 AND searchDate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
GROUP BY `searchTerm`
ORDER BY percent DESC, searchDate DESC
```

I got as far as the code below, but this line `AND searchDate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)` I have not idea how to represent in Rails or if it's even possible.

```
where("results = 0").group('searchTerm').count('searchTerm')
```

I can get around it by issuing a find_by_sql but would like to try to stick to 'The Rails Way'

Thanks

**Edit:**
I have this inside a method of my class called Search like so:

```
def self.no_results
    where("results = 0").group('searchTerm').count('searchTerm')
end
```

**Edit2:**
I had to write it this way:

```
select("searches.*, COUNT(searchTerm) AS percent").where("results = 0 AND searchDate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)" ).group("searchTerm").order("percent DESC, searchDate DESC")
```

Because using `"searchDate > ?", DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)` would give me a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suppose your model is called Search

```
Search
  .select("searches.*, COUNT(searchTerm) AS percent")
  .where("results = ? AND searchDate > ?", 0, DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
  .group("searchTerm")
  .order("percent DESC, searchDate DESC")
```

Comment: Sorry, but how would I put this into my method, it gives me errors if I copy them as you posted these.

Comment: I think I got it, I was just being stupid, let me run it and see what happens.